# Dropdown issues on Mac

Tags: html, macos

I don't know if this question is relevant, but it has become an issue at my workplace, so...

One of our clients (using a Mac) showed us a 'problem' in a dropdown that we made using the  default `<select>` tag. The dropdown has 43 `<option>`'s. In our Windows PC, the dropdown has a scroll bar (as you can see in the screenshot) showing only some items at a time. But in the client's browser, the dropdown shows all the items at once.
Is there a way to have scroll bars on the dropdown on Mac PCs? If no, what possible alternatives can I apply to get rid of this issue? Please note that the dropdown uses HTML's default `<select>` and `<option>` tags and I am hoping not to use any jQuery plugins as an alternative.
Thanks :)

**Edit:** For reference, here's the website - <del>http://webcityhome.com/client/aairportershuttle/reservation.php (On the Pickup Location, go to 'Pier' and select 'Pier no.')</del> **(link defunct)**

This is the Windows screenshot in our PC -
[image: Windows Screenshot]

And this is the Mac screenshot in the client's PC -
[image: Mac Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal, expected behavior of a dropdown list on OS X. OS X uses the entire available vertical space for the list, it does not restrict it to some arbitrary portion of the screen.

I'd tell your client politely to shove it. What he wants to do is alter the default behavior of standard OS provided controls. That's not the job of a website developer, and it's not an issue either. It'd be an issue to change it and provide all users with unexpected behavior.

**Every single dropdown list in OS X works this way.** Ask your client why it's only an issue on *your* site.

Comment: PS: From a UX perspective you *may* want to think about shortening that list or using an alternative control (slider, number input). Super-long lists aren't necessarily the best UI, scrolling or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Really appreciate it :D
Yeah, I've had similar thoughts about looking for an alternative too. But sliders or jQuery based dropdowns are not an option here. I'm trying something right now with plain CSS/HTML which I hope will work. But if you have a suggestion that is simple to use and quick to work with, I'd be really glad! Thanks again @deceze.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a problem on Chrome or Safari on Mac OSX.  Here is a screenshot.
[image]

It displays an arrow to scroll down that is activated on scroll or mouseover.

Comment: Hey @derek_duncan, here's a screenshot of the whole page to give you the idea of the dimensions. http://i.imm.io/OTnQ.png. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this will actually work, but try adding this to your stylesheet:

`select {
height:7em;
overflow:scroll;
}`

Both the `<select>` and `<option>` tags can be stylized with CSS.

Comment: PS - it scrolls on my mac. There might be a setting on the mac you are using to cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a scroll bar, try adding a size attribute, e.g., `<select size="20">`.

Comment: Using size attribute gives me this - http://prntscr.com/m0cb2, not something that I want :s